# Unable to extract IBM Watson assistant logs from multiple pages. How to use pagination to get results for all logs

Tags: python-3.x, api, ibm-watson

Here is what I'm doing:

```
### from ibm_watson import AssistantV1
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
import json

uthenticator = IAMAuthenticator('xxxxxx')
assistant = AssistantV1(version='2020-02-05',authenticator=IAMAuthenticator('xxxxxxxx')
)

assistant.set_service_url('url')
response=assistant.list_logs(workspace_id='workspace_id').get_result()
print(response)
```

Comment: want to retrieve logs from multiple pages and also use request_timestamp filter. Looking for code in python

Comment: Can you document better what it is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to extract all the logs as currently it gives logs upto request_timestamp': '2020-02-27T16:52:54.088Z' and there is pagination information at the end.  'pagination': {'next_url': '/v1/workspaces******}. I am assuming there are more results and they are available on next page. Also Appreciate if you could guide how we can extract logs with specific request_timestamp': '2020-02-27T16:52:54.088Z' for example if I want to extract logs for today's date. Appreciate your help ad I am new to programming and stack_overflow and trying to understand how it works.

Answer (score 4):

There is fairly new information in the API reference about [pagination](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v1?code=python#pagination). Perhaps the information and example there would help.

Here's the info from there about changing the size of the response:

> The default page size is 100 objects. To use a different page size, use the `page_limit` parameter.

And here's the info about a specific page and sort order:

> To request a specific page of results, specify the appropriate value using the `cursor` parameter. When requesting subsequent pages, do not change the values of the `sort` and `page_limit` parameters (if any).
>
> To change the attribute by which results are sorted, use the `sort` parameter [on the method]. If you include multiple sort parameters on the same request, the results are sorted first by the first sorting attribute, then the second, and so on.

And from the `list_logs` method ("List log events in a workspace"):

> `sort`: You can sort by `request_timestamp`.